# Placing Objects in a certain layout(For game)

Tags: java, android, andengine

So this what i want to do, i have a scene right now, and i want to create "Pages" on the scene with level icons i create.

Now i want to be able to set the amount of levels i want to have. for example,

```
int levels = 100;
```

Then i want it to be able to create "Pages". What i mean by pages is it will be space between each of the level sections.

I would like to be able to set the rows and columns like this:

```
int rowsPerPage = 5;
int colPerPage = 10;
```

Each of my level icons are 80x80 width and height.

So with this information i would like be able to place the level icons on rows per page bases and column per page basis.

Each level icon should have some padding space between them.

Once it reaches its makes row and column per page on the first page i would like to create a second page making some space between the first set of rows and columns. Once it reaches is max icon per row it should then start a new row on that page

Right now im not sure where to begin. The reason i am using this is because i have set up gesture detection so my users can scroll from "Page" to "Page" to select a level.

I know this isnt a place to just ask for code, but im stuck on my current project because of this and it would be really great to get some assistance.

Thank you guys in advance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No one will write your code for you if you haven't even attempted it yourself...

This is from google... It may not be exactly what you want. However, it is a start :)

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/menu-scroll-example-t5740.html